# how can I solve lxc container journal mount problem

Tags: ansible, openstack, mount, lxc, linux-containers

I have lxc contariner with the line at its own config

`lxc.mount.entry = /var/log/journal/56abd83f52ed4b53b6bd4c41f3564179 var/log/journal/56abd83f52ed4b53b6bd4c41f3564179 none bind,create=dir 0 0`

but they are not synced. the directory in hosts is older than inside container and i create another line

`lxc.mount.entry = /srv/log/machine1 var/log none bind,create=dir 0 0`

it works perfectly fine for some container and doesnt work for the others.

what's the reason of that

Comment: lxc_version : 4.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the order of mount .
its been fixed in openstack victoria

insertbefore section was added. in upgrade ussuri to victoria we should do it manually.

so the order is like this

first var/log

then /var/log/journal

```
- name: Add bind mount configuration to container
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/var/lib/lxc/{{ inventory_hostname }}/config"
    line: "lxc.mount.entry = {{ item['mount_path'] }} {{ item['bind_dir_path'].lstrip('/') }} none bind,create=dir 0 0"
    insertbefore: "^lxc.mount.entry = .*\\s{{ item['bind_dir_path'].lstrip('/') | regex_replace('/', '\/') }}.*"
    backup: "true"
  with_items:
    - "{{ lxc_default_bind_mounts | default([]) }}"
    - "{{ list_of_bind_mounts | default([]) }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ physical_host }}"
  register: _mc
  tags:
    - common-lxc
```